# AdMob RewardedAd causes Memory leaks (v19.7.0)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

After Analysing with Android profiler I found that My Activity doesn't get garbage collected and is still running after calling finish().
And the cause of this is the AdMob RewardedAd (videos), so I tried to set the reference to the RewardedAd instance to null but it didn't work and the Activity is still leaking.

I've been searching for a solution but I didn't find an appropriate one, so is there a way to stop the memory leak? Or a correct way to implement the RewardedAd without having this issue?

Note : I use the new API of the AdMob RewardedAd (19.7.0)